# В тот день... , когда подали вишнёвый кисель(,) и сестра капризно сказала

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> В тот день мы завтракали втроём, и, когда подали вишнёвый кисель, сестра капризно сказала, что десерт сегодня невкусный.

Это — правильное написание. Объясните, почему первая запятая нужна? Понятно, что "мы завтракали" и "сестра сказала" — две основы. Но у них есть общая часть "в тот день". А если есть общая часть, то запятая не должна ставиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая часть "в тот день" обозначает общий временной промежуток, относящийся к обоим сообщениям, но при этом вторая часть предложения имеет собственный дополнительный конкретизатор времени - придаточное предложение "когда подали вишнёвый кисель", также глаголы имеют разный вид (несов. и сов.).

Соответственно, союз И даже при наличии общего обстоятельства не связывает предложения в одну фразу, поэтому делается пауза, ставится запятая.

Примечание. В правилах Розенталя на эту тему приводятся различные исключения, когда запятая ставится при наличии общего члена.

Comment: Ссылочку бы дали на Розенталя. Я навскидку могу вспомнить только один случай, он тут неприменим.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  Запятая ставится:  Когда Каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днём (Ч.) — придаточная часть относится только к первому простому предложению, а связь его со вторым слабее, на что указывает различный вид глаголов-сказуемых этих предложений.

Comment: Не нашел по вашей ссылке никаких указаний на исключения. За вычетом, естественно, давно известного мне случая повторяющегося союза. Там, правда, есть ряд оговорок, где приводятся соображения, на основании которых член не признается общим, это да. Но все равно нет ничего подходящего под вашу формулировку в отношении какого-то "собственного конкретизатора времени".

Comment: Розенталь  приводит примеры исключений из формального правила, где рассматривает различные ФАКТОРЫ, ПРЕПЯТСТВУЮЩИЕ объединению двух предложений с союзом И в одну фразу. Факторы разные, в частности указывается разный вид глаголов сказуемых.  Здесь важно понять общий принцип этого правила, первопричину, привести несколько примеров, а  ВСЕ частные примеры записать невозможно и не нужно,так как  пользователь  может определить их  сам.

Comment: Если не трудно, укажите конкретно, какой фрагмент текста Розенталя вы называете исключением? Повторюсь, я там никаких исключений не вижу (кроме случая повторяющегося союза, что то весьма условно можно считать исключением). Розенталь последовательно и тщательно приводит примеры, предостерегающие от ошибочного применения правила. Называть их исключениями из правила, у меня язык не повернется.

Comment: И даже если это "исключения", где вводится понятие "конкретизатор времени" - или что-то подобное, влияющее на постановку запятой?

Comment: Если вы категорически против"конкретизатора",то можно считать, что  "в этот день" - это детерминанта (относится ко всему предложению), а придаточное предложение времени имеет уточняющее значение, поэтому у двух предложений нет одинаковой временной привязки, что и препятствует их объединению.

Answer (score 1):

Даю своё понимание, другие ответы меня совершенно не устраивают.
Наличие "киселя"(Niemand) тут никаким боком, а у Розенталя нет ничего про какой-то "конкретизатор"(Sibylla), как, впрочем, и о каких-то других "исключениях". Тут, думаю, вопрос трактовки и понимания авторского подхода.

Во-первых, считаю, что запятая здесь авторская, т. е. возможная в силу авторского прочтения текста, но отнюдь не обязательна. Причина, согласен, заключается в том, что автор своей авторской волей не отнёс "в тот день" к общим членам, хотя мог бы. Мотивировка этого мне в общем-то понятна. "В тот день" имеет слабую смысловую связь со сказанным сестрой, но причина этого совсем не в киселе, а понимании костяка фразы ***"в тот день мы завтракали втроем, и сестра сказала"***. Эта фраза вполне может пониматься двояко, вполне допуская, что в тот день не относится к сказанному сестрой, по сути первая часть сама по себе и отвечает за привязку ко времени: "в тот день, когда мы завтракали втроем, сестра сказала". Это и позволяет считать ве части исходной фразы разнородными, т.е. не имеющими общего члена.

Уточню, что "под общим членом" во всех подобных формулировка правил понимается не просто общий член, а общий **грамматический** член предложения, т.е. синтаксическая и, как правило, семантическая связь двух предложений с этим членом должна быть одинакова. Этот случай у Розенталя уточняется в непомеченном примечании.

> Но: *Когда Каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился
>   шум, какой бывает только днём (Ч.)* — придаточная часть относится
>   только к первому простому предложению, а связь его со вторым слабее,
>   на что указывает различный вид глаголов-сказуемых этих предложений

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

(Ссылку даю по тому же источнику, что и Sibylla)

Правда, здесь случай куда более очевидный из-за различного вида сказуемых, но суть-то отражена. ***Различные виды связей "общего члена" с двумя предложениями позволяет не считать его общим (в понимании, требуемом для правила постановки запятой)***.

Answer (score 0):

> > Но у них есть общая часть "в тот день".

Ни в коем случае. Даже и близко такого нет. Не надо мудрить! "В тот день сестра капризно сказала"?! Нет, она сказала, когда подали кисель.

Comment: *Ни в коем случае.* - почему? Это факт, без всякого мудрежа. *Нет, она сказала, когда подали кисель* - это что, был другой день?

Comment: Тот же самый, ну и что? По такой логике, если впереди есть обстоятельство времени, то для любого ССП это будет "общий второстепенный член".

Comment: По какой "такой"? Я ничего о той логике не знаю. Меня вообще-то интересует, ***по какой логике вы сочли, что "в тот день" не относится ко второй части***, основываясь, видимо, на наличии киселя. Если вы о ней, это странная логика.

Comment: Пускай странная. Но я ни на минуту не задумался, ставить запятую или нет, а вы задумались, да еще как. Пусть и всегда моя странная логика меня так же не подводит, а на "странность" я согласен.

Comment: Спасибо. Более вопросов не имею. PS Да, я задумался. И не вижу в том ничего плохого.